# Google Apps Script url "routes"

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I realize this is just because I'm dense, but...

What's a simple way to implement the "routing" functionality that's common in most modern web app frameworks (Rails, Sinatra, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an url like .../dev/pageToRouteTo
and then access 'pageToRouteTo' from the doGet()

What you can do, is use a parameter e.g.
.../dev?NextPage=pageToRouteTo and then

run code like:

```
function doGet(e){
  if('parameters' in e && 'NextPage' in e.parameters){
     loadPage(e.parameters.NextPage[0])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get the route parameters:

```js
function doGet(request){
  let path = request.pathInfo;
  let routeParams = path.split("/");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The [doGet() function has access to GET parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp#doGetParams), but not the URL itself, so you can't really do what you're thinking of with Apps Script.

What you could do is use Google Apps Script as a backend to a web app running something like AngularJS, which has client-side routing. You have to host the app elsewhere (the Caja sanitiser doesn't support serving AngularJS yet), and you have to use JSONP as your exchange format, as you can't use Apps Script apps for AJAX endpoints.

Here is an example from [Keisuke Ohashi](https://plus.google.com/112329532641745322160/about):

- [Front end](https://googledrive.com/host/0BwzWIlBMCiR9SlZkbkFqZ21YeFk/index.html) (note: hosted on Google Drive)
- [Content service code](https://script.google.com/d/1nJ0ygMy1nEPnT1qky3lETahm16iqblNVaYc6c8ZLHQUHgYTpLVqwcj3u/edit)
- [ScriptDB code](https://script.google.com/d/13U6Pb7tY_I5Tihgo9lIn8XcNFXmWQmJlpGbSH1_rOSyqQguHa5vByRUi/edit)

Comment: So then it wouldn't be possible to use something like Ember JS as the framework for GAS web app?

Comment: The links are invalid